# How to install Next.js correctly

Tags: next.js

When I try to install Next.js using `npx-create-next-app@latest`, this error appears. Please give solutions.

> npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency typescript@>=3.3.1 included from eslint-config-next will no
> npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
> npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
> npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @opentelemetry/api@^1.1.0 included from next will no
> npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
> npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
> npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency sass@^1.3.0 included from next will no
> npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
> npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
> npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency ts-node@>=9.0.0 included from postcss-load-config will no
> npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
> npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
> npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@2.3.3
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19045
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\panka\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
> npm ERR! node v20.11.0
> npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
>
> npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type: npm:string-width@^4.2.0
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
> npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19045
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\panka\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
> npm ERR! node v20.11.0
> npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
>
> npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type: npm:strip-ansi@^6.0.1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
> npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19045
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\panka\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
> npm ERR! node v20.11.0
> npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
>
> npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type: npm:wrap-ansi@^7.0.0
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
> npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
> npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @swc/core@>=1.2.50 included from ts-node will no
> npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
> npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
> npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @swc/wasm@>=1.2.50 included from ts-node will no
> npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
> npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
> npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @types/node@* included from ts-node will no
> npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
> npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
> npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency typescript@>=2.7 included from ts-node will no
> npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
> npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
> npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing @next/swc-win32-arm64-msvc@14.0.4
> npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing @next/swc-linux-arm64-gnu@14.0.4
> npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency typescript@>=4.2.0 included from ts-api-utils will no
> npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
> npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
> npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @swc/helpers@^0.5.0 included from @swc/core will no
> npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
> npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
> npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/@swc/core-linux-x64-gnu/-/core-linux-x64-gnu-1.3.104.tgz
> npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
> npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc@14.0.4
> npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing @next/swc-linux-x64-gnu@14.0.4
> npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing @next/swc-linux-x64-musl@14.0.4
> npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing @next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc@14.0.4

I tried many methods but error appears again and again.

Comment: its `npx create-next-app@latest` not `npx-create-next-app@latest`

Answer (score 1):

You are misstyping here I guess

```
npx-create-next-app@latest
```

Try this one

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```